# Fetch Data from an external MSSQL Database in a Managed WP hosting

Tags: php, javascript, sql, hosting, mssql

SO, my client is using a managed WP hosting, which is why I can't install MSSQL drivers in his server. I am building a plugin for him to fetch some data from their office's MSSQL server. Now, I have built the plugin in my localhost by connecting directly using SQLSRV. But this plugin won't work on his site because I can't fetch the data without mssql driver.

Can you please guide me through this issue? How can I fetch the data with basic PHP or Javascript without depending on his server. Any idea for a workaround is appreciated.

Comment: Does this workaround work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659021/1094518

Comment: Thank @PatJ, I will try this when I go home. This looks too good to be true

Comment: It doesn't work. I think this is only supported in microsoft servers.

Comment: My client has a managed Godaddy hosting. I get this error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "COM" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\vp\wp-content\plugins\vp-releases\vp_connection.php:4 Stack trace: #0

Comment: If their host doesn't support MSSQL, then their host doesn't support MSSQL, and this won't work. You will need to speak to the host to see if they can accommodate you, otherwise they will need to use a different host.